# How to build OpenCV for Android with selected modules

Tags: android, opencv, build

I have an app that use a few functions from OpenCV, i think it is an overkill to force the installation of OpenCV Manager for a few functions.

I am looking to a way on building OpenCV native modules only with the functions I need, then pack them on my app, in order to reduce size and avoid installing unnecessary code.

For now I am using canny, adaptive threshold, gaussian blur, image conversions from color to grayscale, decoding and encoding jpeg. Images are taken from camera using native android functions (not OpenCV).

Is this achievable?

Comment: It may take a minute and is kind of the opposite of your thinking (including what you want), but you can exclude certain modules from dependencies in gradle. You could look into excluding the modules you don't need and keeping the ones you do. There may be a counter-function (include modules explicitly) but I haven't ever seen or worked with that before.

Comment: OpenCV is opensource. Grab the code you need and make your own little library (beware of the license / copyright / etc...)

Comment: @Miki, I didn't found a good guide on building it, seems like the building of OpenCV  Manager is very hard and with a lot of dependencies. License is MIT, so I think it can be used on pretty much anything, but my app is open source, so no problem with that also.